# How to get JSON representation from JTS Geometry?

Tags: postgis, json, jts-topology-suite

I'm using JTS (http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) and need to get a JSON representation of a Point :

Hibernate beam:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name="the_geom")
private Point theGeom;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
  id_city serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  the_geom geometry,
  id_user integer,
  CONSTRAINT cities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_city),
  CONSTRAINT fk2de48dcf3c0b0090 FOREIGN KEY (id_user)
      REFERENCES users (id_user) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I need something like:

```
jsonString = someClass.convertToJson( myBeam.getTheGeom() )
```

Comment: the JTS home page is actually at http://tsusiatsoftware.net/ - it's now at version 1.12 - is that what you are using?

Comment: Well, sounds strange a project having 2 diferents home pages. I'm in 1.8, but how can the new version helps me in this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From @Mike Toews' tip:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cities") 
public class City {

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    @Column(name="the_geom")
    private Point theGeom;

    public String asJson() {
        GeometryJSON g = new GeometryJSON();
        return g.toString(theGeom) ; 
    }
}
```

You will need at least these JARs:

```
gt-api-10.0.jar
gt-epsg-extension-10.0.jar
gt-epsg-wkt-10.0.jar
gt-geojson-10.2.jar
gt-geometry-10.0.jar
gt-metadata-10.0.jar
gt-opengis-10.0.jar
gt-referencing-10.0.jar
jts-1.8.jar
jtsio-1.8.jar
```

and some few others I can't remember now, because I don't really need GeoTools.

Comment: You will not need the Hibernate stuff, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use a SELECT statement with [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) to let the server return the data as [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) text.

On a related note, it looks like [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) has extended JTS to have a [GeometryJSON class](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html) for the feature you are looking for within a pure Java environment.

Comment: I know `ST_AsGeoJSON` and is not what I need. Looks like GeoTools is more close.

Comment: By leading me to right direction, I will reward you, but you don't realy give a clear answer, so I will accept mine.